Can TikZ/Graph do automatic placement taking into account edge label length?
I wish to automatically draw a graph, with labels of diverse lengths on the edges.  For it to be pretty, I need that:

If a node is automatically placed below another, then the edge label length should not impact the distance between the nodes;
If it is automatically placed to the right of another, then the nodes should be distanced so that the label can sit on the edge.

Example:  The left hand side here is produced by \graph, and the right with manual placement, which I'd like to avoid.

Question:  How can this be achieved automatically with \graph?
MWE:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,quotes}

\begin{document}

\tikz \graph [edge quotes={auto}] {
  1 ->["hello world"] {2, 3};
};

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (1) {1};
  \node (2) at (2.5cm, 0) {2};
  \node (3) at (1cm, -1cm) {3};

  \draw (1) -> node[above] {hello world} (2)
        (1) -> node[fill=white, fill opacity=.5,text opacity=1] {hello world} (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

